# Does it matter to use が or は in one sentence lines, for example: textbook questions?

Tags: particles, は-and-が

So when doing textbooks, it just asks me to write translate from english to japanese.
The sentence I was just doing was, "Since my family will come to Japan, I will show them around Kyoto. In this one sentence, does it matter if I use は or が? 家族は/家族が

Do you think が or は works better?

My thinking is that you use は when you want to emphasize what comes next, and が for when you want to emphasize when comes before.

If someone asked me, what is your family doing? Then I think は would be better, or if someone asked me who is coming to Japan, I think が would work better.

But here, in one setences lines and stuff, is there really one thing you want to empasize? I could be totally wrong, in which case feel free to correct me. ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct particle choice depends mainly on whether 私の家族 is already in the ["universe of discourse"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51/5010). If you mention your family for the first time in the conversation, you would say "私の家族**が**来月日本に来るので...". However, in the last half of an essay about your family, you say "私の家族**は**来月日本に来るので...".

If this is the only sentence in a translation task and no further context is available, it's probably better to choose が.

<sub>(By the way, you should not "thank in advance" like that. Please read [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/820/5010).)</sub>

Comment: Can I follow a rule for most times that, if the topic is new, use が, and if it isn't, use は

Answer (score -1):

From what I learned, I will say the sentence as 私の家族が日本に来るので、私は京都を案内します。
As the major subject is you, you are indicating that you are doing something. The first half of the sentence is more of the reasoning for why you are doing this.
On the other hand, when someone is asking what is your family doing, the subject is your family! Hence why you will usually use は.